# Is it wrong to say "very recommended" for something

Tags: word-usage, collocations

I know that the word [recommended](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/recommend) collocates with the words highly, heartily or thoroughly. However, maybe most of the non-native speakers tend to use the word very before recommended because of the direct translation of their native languages and it is common to see "very recommended" on the Internet. I wonder do native speakers use this collocation or is it only used by non-native speakers of English? Does it irritate your ears when you hear it?

Comment: I think I would use "widely" or "highly". "Very" doesn't irritate my ears, but I wouldn't say it.

Comment: We tend not to use _very_ with verb participles like _recommended, loved, admired_ and so on, but _very much, greatly, highly_ etc.